# Binding properties of selected object in combobox to TextBox in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, combobox, textbox

I'm using MVVM to load text files and to show their content.

**Model**

`MyFile.cs` has a `Name` and `Text` // Implements the INotifyPropertyChanged

`MyFileRepository.cs` // collection of my loaded files

**ViewModel**

`OpenFileCommand` to load a file and add it to the _filerepository object

`FileCollection` that's bound to the View

**View**

`Button` to fire the `OpenCommand`

`ComboBox` to show the names of the loaded files

`TextBox` to show the content of selected file in combobx

```
<Button Name="OpenFile" Command="{Binding OpenFileCommand}">
<ComboBox  Name="FilesList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FileCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
<TextBox Name="FileContent" Text="{Binding the Text of selected file in combobx "/>
```

How to bind the Text property of MyFile selected in combobx to the TextBox?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest approach would be element binding:

```
<TextBox Name="FileContent"
         Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Text,ElementName=FilesList} />
```

So that's binding to the Text property of the SelectedItem in your FilesList ComboBox, which (if everything's wired up the way I think it is) is of type MyFile.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't expect that it'll be so easy :)

Answer (score 0):

Without element binding you could add the property "SelectedItem" (Type: MyFile) to your VM and bind it to the SelectedItem property of your combobox (mode=twoway).
Now your TextBox.Text-Property should look like:

```
<TextBox Name="FileContent"
         Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Text} />
```